# Servlet getRequestDispatcher() relative to root of project

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am calling a jsp from within my servlet. How can I specify the location of the jsp I am trying to call relative to the root of my project? (src/com/.........)

Comment: Use `webapps` as root folder

Comment: I don't have a webapps folder in my project

Comment: under which folder your JSP files are ?

Comment: under the source (src/com/servlets/results.jsp)

Comment: so `servlets` would be an educated guess to use as `root-folder` but better search for web.xml file - it might be defined there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not think in terms of where the files are located in your source project. You must think in terms of where the files are located inside the web archive that will be deployed in the container.

So if the JSP, in the war file (or exploded war file) is at the root, then the path should be `/results.jsp`.